# how to clear all Android application cache data from android

Tags: android

I am searching the code to clear all cache data from android mobile. I used PackageManager and Method api for clearing the cache data from android but this will happened with single application cache data

but I want all android application cache data should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for one application cache

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
        try {
            File dir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                deleteDir(dir);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

try this also.

```
public static void trimCache(Context context) {
    File dir = context.getCacheDir();
    if(dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()){
        File[] children = dir.listFiles();
        if (children == null) {
            // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
        } else {
            File temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                temp = children[i];
                temp.delete();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I called from onCreate() method its not working and still cache data is there.

Comment: Can you share your Activity class